# Oracle Database docker linux VM - Laptop connection

Tags: oracle, docker

I have an Oracle database running in a Linux VM. The way i started the docker is using the following command

```
sudo docker run -d --name my_db --net oac_net -p 1521:1521 -P --shm-size=4G bi.docker.oraclecorp.com/database/enterprise:12.1.0.2
```

This is running inside a Linux VM.

```
[oracle@07f1d37f71c9 /]$ hostname -i
172.18.0.2
```

I would like to connect to this database docker from my laptop. The TNS entry in my laptop is like the following

```
odidocker =   (DESCRIPTION =     (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 172.18.0.2)(PORT = 1521))     
(CONNECT_DATA =       (SERVER = DEDICATED)       (SERVICE_NAME = ORCL.localdomain)     )   )
PDBORCL=
(DESCRIPTION =
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 172.18.0.2)(PORT = 1521))
  (CONNECT_DATA =
(SERVER = DEDICATED)
(SERVICE_NAME = pdborcl.localdomain)
  ))
```

Trying to connect using the following command

```
sqlplus system/welcome1@odidocker
```

the error we are getting is the following

```
ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified
```

What is the mistake i am making. Could someone please help.

Thanks

Bala

Comment: With `--net oac_net` you have made the container to connect to the specified network. You have to be connected to the same network to reach it.

Comment: Thanks @henry I have other dockers which gets connected to that network besides the DB docker. Wondering how to get my laptop connected to that network. Guess that is not going to be possible

Comment: One way would be to `docker exec` into the container.

Comment: @Henry can you please help me understand `docker exec` Should i do this in my laptop ?